# RESTful Application Structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, rest

I am new to RESTful architecture or at least new to using it properly I have only had true experience with SOAP.  I am having a problem wrapping my head around some things.  I know there are other questions that are similar but none, that I have found, answer my question satisfactorily.

I am just starting this app so I want to get it started the right way and what I am looking at now is a user registration screen.  I have two validation calls that occur before the registration form is even submitted.  First I have a validation call that checks to make sure the email entered by the user is unique and second I have a validation call that checks to make sure an access code we provide to the customer exists in the database.

I currently have it structured as a **POST** (which I believe should be a **GET**) and I have an action argument that defines what I am wanting to do.  So for the email I have an argument string such as

```
action=validateemail&value=email@email.com
```

and it is calling the User action of my MembershipController.  I am entirely sure this is wrong as I should only be using the verbs **GET**, **POST**, **PUT**, and **DELETE** yet I am defining my own verb using the action argument.

Honestly, I don't know how to do this.  I believe the User should be my resource but possibly for the email validation Email should be my resource.  I guess what I am asking is how would you do what I am trying to do?  I know some of you might just say do all the validation upon the submit, but I would prefer to do it both ways really.  I would like the asynchronous validation as well as the validation I will perform when the user submits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do something similar and our resource is called "Account".  For the validation I would do a GET for the Account specified and validate the HTTP return code.  I would expect a 404 - Not Found to let me know the proposed account doesn't exist.  If they passed in mangled data a 400 - Bad Request would tell you something was wrong.  To create the Account a POST of the same resource would do.  To do something like change a password, a PUT might be appropriate.  I think that if you already are making a trip to the server, you might as well return the account(200 - Ok on the GET) if it exists to save yourself the second trip.